# The limit of $\ln(1+\ln(2+\ln(3+...+\ln(n)))...)$

Tags: limits, logarithms

Does this limit: 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln(1+\ln(2+\ln(3+...+\ln(n)))...)$$

exist ? And if yes, which value does it have ?

Comment: Could you give us some background for this question? Was it posed as an exercise, or did it arise naturally, or is it just curiosity? (Personally, I would bet the limit exists, due to the slow growth of the logarithm. And I would be surprised if you can find the limit. But I love surprises!)

Comment: I was inspired by the limit sqrt(1/2+(1/3^(1/3+...)))

Comment: The inverse symbolic calculator does not find a closed expression.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get a proof of convergence along these lines: Show by induction on $k$ that, for all $n$,
$$\ln(n+\ln(n+1+\ln(n+2+\cdots+\ln(n+k))))\le\sum_{j=0}^k\frac{n!}{(n+j)!}\ln(n+j).$$
The basic inequality you will need in the induction step has the form
$$\ln(n+a)<\ln n+\frac an,$$
which you apply with $a=\ln(n+1+\ln(n+2+\cdots+\ln(n+k)))$.

So, for $n=1$ you get
$$\ln(1+\ln(2+\ln(3+\cdots+\ln(k+1))))\le\sum_{j=0}^k\frac{1}{j!}\ln(j),$$
and the series on the right clearly converges. The sequence on the left, on the other hand, is increasing, so boundedness implies convergence.

Answer (score 2):

Pari/GP:

```
n=28
res=0
forstep(x=n,1,-1,res =log(x+res))
res
 %553 = 0.820359862208789788473466794941
```

It does not change in the visible digits if $n$ is furtherly increased...

---

It is nice to invert the procedure.
Assume $t_n$ is the evaluation of the above with some $n$ given, so $t_n \approx 0.82035986...$ then let's look what happens if we invert the operation:

```
 t_n =res \\ save the result which we just got in a fixed variable
          \\ perform iteration on the inverse function
 x = t_n;for(k=1,n+3, x = exp(x)-k; print(x));
```

The result is:

```
1.27131705165
1.56554547884
1.78528449551
1.96127566254
2.10838918962
2.23496562706
2.34616059168
2.44538852642
...
3.41221000321
3.33220451018
-1.19274014861 E-170   \\ this is at iteration 28
-28.0000000000   \\ with small fractional parts exp(-k)
-30.0000000000   \\ ... 
-31.0000000000
```

So if we assume some limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} t_n$ then with an appropriate $\delta_m$ if we iterate from $$x_0=t_\infty+\delta_m \\ x_k=\exp(x_{k-1})-k $$ some $x_m=0$, $x_{m+1}=-m$ occurs...

Comment: I have done this in a similar way.

Answer (score 1):

Let us construct a similar expression where we actually do know the exact answer. Let us say the series starting with the number $2$ having the result of every logarithm being equal to the number it is added to:

$$\ln(2+\ln(3.69 ...+\ln(20.11 ...+\ln(...))))$$

We can calculate each term in this expression as:

$$t_{1}=2,\ t_{n}=\frac{\exp(t_{n-1})}{2}$$

Since this is a super-exponential series and the gap between the first two terms is greater than $1$ it is safe to conclude that every term in the series is greater than the same term in the series of natural numbers.

As increasing any of the terms in the original expression can only cause the resulting value to be greater, this new expression can be used to calculate an upper bound for the original expression. We can in the original expression, for $n\ge2$ replace any $n+\ln(...)$ with $2n$, to get a result that is greater than the original expression, and thus a useful upper bound. Pair this with the lower bound of replacing with $n$ and you have a proof of convergence and a method of calculating arbitrarily precise upper and lower bounds.