# Are quaternions algebraic numbers?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, quaternions

Like the question states, are all quaternions algebraic numbers, i.e. can they be derived from (inverse) exponentiation of rational numbers? This is in my understanding what makes numbers like the imaginary unit algebraic; does this apply to the units *j* and *k* as well?

This question may seem extremely simple, but please understand that I don't have a background in formal mathematics and don't even fully understand what quaternions are, I was just wondering about the above and not being able to find the question stated precisely as such.

Comment: So to be clear, you mean “algebraic over the rational numbers”?  Not even all of the real numbers are algebraic over the rationals, so obviously those reals (as quaternions) will not be either.

Comment: Secondly, I’m not sure what “(derived from (inverse) exponentiation” is, but it does not sound like what I learned “algebraic” means.  Are you sure you know what algebraic means?

Comment: $j^2=-1$, so $j$ can be seen as an algebraic number in this sense. The same with $i$ or $k$. But $\pi j$ is not a root of a polynomial equation with rational coefficients as $\pi$ is not one either.

Comment: Also bears mention that among algebraic numbers, that  are roots of polynomials of degree at least five, some can not be expressed in terms of radicals

Comment: Within quaternions we have the further anomaly that whenever $u=ai+bj+ck$ is a unit vector, it also satisfies the equation $u^2+1=0$. Non-commutativity makes things hairy. Within a number field we have a unique maximal subring consisting of algebraic integers within the field. Such things don't exist inside quaternions (and its subdivision algebras).

Comment: Depending on where you look for your definition, an algebraic number is [a complex number that is a root of a polynomial with rational coefficients](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Algebraic_Number). Or it's a [real number that is a root of a polynomial equation with integer coefficients](https://www.britannica.com/science/algebraic-number). I haven't seen such a definition for quaternions, but that doesn't mean it doesn't exist.

Comment: Elaborating on Jyrki's comment above, note that for example there are uncountably many quaternions satisfying $x^2=-1$, for example. So if "algebraic quaternion" means "quaternion which is a zero of some non-constant polynomial over the rationals," then the existence of a non-algebraic quaternion isn't *just* an immediate cardinality argument. Rather, we need to follow the *argument* of the uncountability of $\mathbb{R}$: we build a decreasing sequence of closed balls of nonzero radius $(B_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that no quaternion in $B_i$ is a zero of the $i$th nonconstant polynomial.

Comment: For this we simply need the result that the zero set of a non-constant polynomial in the quaternions is nowhere-dense, which is still true.

Comment: @DavidK Yes, you can use the same definition for quaternions, which is what rschwieb means by algebraic over Q.

Comment: Thank you for the answers! I was of course referring to the "units" themselves, since they can be multiplied by any real number and the set of real algebraic numbers is just a subset of ℝ. I've also realised from your answers that quaternions is what logically happens to the set of complex numbers when you permit non-commutative multiplication. Very interesting, thank you once again.

Comment: What does "can they be derived from (inverse) exponentiation of rational numbers" mean?

Comment: @runway44 The set of algebraic numbers can be formed by raising any rational number to the power of any other rational number. I say inverse since we are chiefly interested in the roots of rational numbers when dealing with algebraic numbers, i.e. exponentiation by fractions.

Comment: Then "(inverse) exponentiation of rational numbers" is a needlessly vague way to express that. And it's not true. For instance, $1+\sqrt{2}$ is algebraic, but it is not expressible as a rational raised to a rational power (it fits under the broader category of "radical expression," which means built from a combination of rationals, the four arithmetic operations, and radicals). More significantly, "most" algebraic numbers are not expressible as radical expressions at all, for instance the roots of $x^5-x-1$.

Comment: @runway44 $\sqrt[r]{b}=b^{\frac{1}{r}}$, any arithmetic operations applied beyond this are of course meant to be implicit in my definition. I was, however, made aware of roots of odd-ordered polynomials of the 5th order and beyond by a previous commenter. Nevertheless, according to Wolfram Alpha, the roots of such polynomials are given by the generalized hypergeometric series, which is a power series of rational coefficients. This means that my definition totally still applies if we permit series, haha.

Comment: But *any* analytic function is given by a series.

Comment: @runway44 I know, but it's a funny coincidence (and considering what I know about math, probably not really a coincidence) that all algebraic numbers happen to specifically be power series involving only rational numbers, completely congruently with my initial assumptions, heh.

Comment: All real numbers are series involving only rationals.

Comment: @runway44 [There appear to be examples of real numbers which are seemingly impossible to represent as well-formed rational series.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/586606/the-limit-of-ln1-ln2-ln3-lnn)

Comment: Every real is a series involving only rationals - indeed, every real number has a decimal expansion, for example (like $\pi=3+0.1+0.04+\cdots$). If by "well-formed rational series" you mean ones where the $n$th term can be written down explicitly as a function of $n$, then sure - there are only countably many so-called "definable numbers," after all. No idea what you think the link you just gave has to do with this, though.